# link to DESCRIPTION file does not work in R

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I'm writing a package in R using devtools (version 1.131.3) and roxygen2 (version 6.0.1) and everything is working correctly except that the link to the DESCRIPTION file does nothing. In other words, if I load my package in R and click the "DESCRIPTION file" link nothing happens.

The description file does show up under the "Files" tab when I am editing the package. So the file exists, and R is aware of it, but for some reason it's not connected to the hyperlink. How do I get that file to associate with that link?

I am using R version 3.4.1.

Comment: Where are you "clicking"? RStudio? The R application itself? What OS? Windows? macOS? Linux? If it's RStudio on macOS High Sierra, switch to one of the RStudio dailies. There's an issue with how macOS reports the file type.

Comment: FWIW: Seems to be a [common problem](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/210870047-New-R-package-link-to-DESCRIPTION-broken)

Comment: This is in Windows 7 via R Studio. How do you load description files in the application itself? It'd like to try that to figure out if it is my files or R studio that is the problem.